# Aliasing (use ... as ...) all files in a directory

Tags: php, alias

I'm currently trying to optimise the framework we develop websites with, and one of the thing that bothers me is the aliasing of our classes. Right now we have one huge list of all the classes that are needed, and we have to add/remove classes based on necessity.

I would like it to go as automated as possible. We have four folders with classes that are used on each website, so I tried the following:

```
$directories = array(
    '../classes/site/database', 
    '../classes/site/utils', 
    '../classes/creabea/utils', 
    '../classes/creabea/database'
);

foreach($directories as $dir){
    $dir_contents = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach($dir_contents as $item){
        if(!$item->isDot()){
            if($item->isDir()){
                foreach(new DirectoryIterator($item->getPath().'/'.$item->__toString()) as $file_l2){ 
                    if(!$file_l2->isDot()){
                        $temppath = preg_replace('(\.\./)', '', $file_l2->getPath());
                        $path = preg_replace('/\//g', '\\', $temppath);
                        $classname = preg_replace('\.class\.php', '', $file_l2->__toString());
                        use $path.'\\'.$classname;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $temppath = preg_replace('(\.\./)', '', $item->getPath());
                $path = preg_replace('/\//g', '\\', $temppath);
                $classname = preg_replace('\.class\.php', '', $item->__toString());
                use $path.'\\'.$classname;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the end it didn't work because you can't call `use` inside of functions or loops or things like that: `use` always has to be in the global scope.

Is there another way to make the aliasing an automated process, while still maintaining the global scope?

Comment: Why do you need import everything and their mother in the first place? Just alias / import the namespaces / fully qualified names you are actually going to use.

Comment: Because we use a lot of classes for our websites, to make them as dynamic as possible. Each section of websites has a separate class, each database-table has their own class, we have classes to read and manipulate the URL, a class for SEO, etcetera, etcetera.

Comment: But you don't ever need them all in a single file unless your design is so utterly broken that your entire application runs in a single file. In which case you have bigger problems than not being able to define `use` at runtime.

Comment: All those preg_replace functions could be implemented using str_replace(). And both preg_replace and str_replace can perform multiple operations in a single call when supplied with an array. Both would be much more efficient. Using glob() rather than DirectoryIterator would result in less code. (and your making the system less dynamic, and undermining the whoile reason for namespaces by aliasing in the global namespace)

Comment: @PeeHaa Well... Ehh. Before you laugh, I wanna make clear that I started learning PHP when I joined this job, so this is all I know. ...we do use one big index.php file, which shows different pages based on the requested URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope

> importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

You cannot enclose use statements with an if block, nor use any runtime things to auto import.

One way is to use a preprocessor that automatically scans and adds the classes inside that namespace.

Comment: The classes are imported without problem, we have an autoloader that imports them all. What I'm looking for is a way to add aliases for the classes. It's basically a champagne problem, because (as far as I know) the only difference for us is that we can type `$content = new Content();` instead of `$content = new /site/database/Content();`. Anyway, the classes are imported with the autoloader, that's not the problem.

Comment: By "import", we mean the action of registering an alias (creating a `use` statement). The preprocessor I meant was about adding use statements, not to include a PHP file.